# jquery bind event, inserted table row won't respond to events

Tags: jquery, events

I'm inserting a table row into a table, its getting messy anyway. I've a function that gets called when one of 3 text fields changes, this works fine I'm using the "inputfield" class to attach the event. But when I insert the row it wont act the same was even though it has the same class tag.

So I'm trying to bind the event to it and that's not working either any ideas why?

```
//code for inserted row
var $html='<tr class="newrow" id="newrow'+$totrecords+'"><td><div id="discountlist_'+$totrecords+'">'+$totrecords+'</div></td><td><label for="ProductProductCode'+$totrecords+'"></label><input name="data[Product][product_code'+$totrecords+']" type="text" id="ProductProductCode'+$totrecords+'"/></td><td><label for="ProductHeight'+$totrecords+'"></label><input name="data[Product][height'+$totrecords+']" type="text" value="0" id="ProductHeight'+$totrecords+'"/></td><td><label for="ProductWidth'+$totrecords+'"></label><input name="data[Product][width'+$totrecords+']" type="text" value="0" id="ProductWidth'+$totrecords+'"/></td><td><label for="ProductPrice'+$totrecords+'"></label><input name="data[Product][price'+$totrecords+']" type="text" id="ProductPrice'+$totrecords+'" class="fieldinput" /></td><td><label for="ProductDiscountPercent'+$totrecords+'"></label><input name="data[Product][discount_percent'+$totrecords+']" type="text" id="ProductDiscountPercent'+$totrecords+'" class="fieldinput"/></td><td><label for="ProductDiscountListprice'+$totrecords+'"></label><input name="data[Product][discount_listprice'+$totrecords+']" type="text" id="ProductDiscountListprice'+$totrecords+'" /></td><td><label for="ProductQuantity'+$totrecords+'"></label><input name="data[Product][quantity'+$totrecords+']" type="text" id="ProductQuantity'+$totrecords+'" class="fieldinput"/></td><td><div class="total" id="total_'+$totrecords+'"></div</td>';


    //method 1 insert the row
    $(this).closest('TR').after($html);

    //bind event to productprice table
    $("#ProductPrice"+$totrecords).bind("change",calculateTotal);


function I'm trying to call

//custom function
var calculateTotal = function(){

    alert('ok');

    var $discountpercent = null;
    var $total=null;
    var $quantity=null;
    var $id=null;

    //get id of textbox
    var $id=$(this).attr('id');

    //get the row id
    //need to fix this and get all chars to the right of the
    $id=$id.toString();
    var myArray = $id.split('_');   
    $id=myArray[1]; 


    var $listprice= $("#listprice_"+$id).val();

    //turn entered number into %
    $discountpercent= $("#discountpercent_"+$id).val()/100;

    $discountlistprice=$listprice-($listprice*$discountpercent);    
    $quantity=$("#quantity_"+$id).val();

    //calculate total   
    $total=$quantity*$discountlistprice;

    //set the value
    $("#discountlistprice_"+$id).val($discountlistprice);

    //set the total by changing the total div
    $("#total_"+$id).html($total);  
}
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle with as little code as possible to help make your question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events need to be rebound to function on new DOM elements. You can use the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (from jQuery v1.7, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) function to apply it to all future elements or you can simply rebind it after insertion.

.live() (pre 1.7):

```
//bind event to productprice table
    $("#ProductPrice"+$totrecords).live("change",calculateTotal);
```

.on() (1.7 and higher):

```
$("#ProductPrice"+$totrecords).on("change",calculateTotal);
```

Comment: im trying to do that with;

    //bind event to productprice table
    '$("#ProductPrice"+$totrecords).bind("change",calculateTotal);'

doestn work for me

Comment: Cool :) Out of interest did you use .on() or live()? Which version of jQuery are you using? (Just curious).